# Bootstrap 3 Full Page Image background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full page background image on my page using the following CSS:

```
.full {
background: url(images/background.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This is attached to the HTML class:

```
<html class="full">
```

I am now trying to put content on top of this using the basic :

```
<div class="container">Text Here</div>
```

The outcome is causing the container to push the background image down and put the content above it. How can I get this content to float on top of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably down to this line in the bootstrap.css

```
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Which *may* be giving the impression your background image is being pushed down, but in reality is just applying a white background the height of your container content over the image.

One option to fix this is just override the `body` css in your custom css:

```
body {
  background: transparent;
}
```